# Как по клику прервать выполнение предыдущего скрипта. JS

Tags: javascript, функции

У меня есть такой эффект печатающей машинки. Сайт у меня 3-х язычный. При смене языка я хочу, чтобы скрипт выполнялся повторно с новым языком. Для этого я добавил событие onclick. Все работает, но есть баг, если мы изменим язык во время выполнения скрипта, новый будет выполняться поверх старого.

Как в моем случае я могу остановить старый сценарий и выполнить новый?

Я попытался использовать `return`, как писали в других ответах, попытался использовать `clearTimeout`, но все равно не работает.

```js
var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
  langText = "Hi!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
(function e() {
  if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
    document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
    var t = text.slice(-1);
    if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
    setTimeout(e, 100);
  }
}());
document.querySelector('.en').onclick = function() {
  var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
    langText = "Hi!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
  (function e() {
    if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
      document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
      var t = text.slice(-1);
      if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
      setTimeout(e, 100);
    }
  }());
};
document.querySelector('.de').onclick = function() {
  var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
    langText = "Hallo!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
  (function e() {
    if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
      document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
      var t = text.slice(-1);
      if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
      setTimeout(e, 100);
    }
  }());
};
document.querySelector('.ru').onclick = function() {
  var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
    langText = "Привет!<br>Текст,<br>Текст ";
  (function e() {
    if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
      document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
      var t = text.slice(-1);
      if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
      setTimeout(e, 100);
    }
  }());
};
```

```css
.lang{
  display: flex;
}
.lang a{
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.lang a:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.lang a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
  <a class="en" href="#">English</a>
  <a class="de" href="#">Deutsche</a>
  <a class="ru" href="#">Русский</a>
</div>
<div class="index-title-main">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно вы не до конца поняли как пользоваться clearTimeout, у меня получилось при помощи него решить задачу. *Подробнее о clearTimeout смотрите тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout*

```js
// здесь будет наш идентификатор таймаута 
var mytimeout = 0;
//
var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
  langText = "Hi!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
(function e() {
  if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
    document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
    var t = text.slice(-1);
    if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
    mytimeout = setTimeout(e, 100);
  }
}());
document.querySelector('.en').onclick = function() {clearTimeout(mytimeout) //очищаем Timeout при новом запуске
  var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
    langText = "Hi!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
  (function e() {
    if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
      document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
      var t = text.slice(-1);
      if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
      mytimeout = setTimeout(e, 100);
    }
  }());
};
document.querySelector('.de').onclick = function() {clearTimeout(mytimeout)//очищаем Timeout при новом запуске
  var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
    langText = "Hallo!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
  (function e() {
    if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
      document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
      var t = text.slice(-1);
      if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
      mytimeout = setTimeout(e, 100);
    }
  }());
};
document.querySelector('.ru').onclick = function() {clearTimeout(mytimeout)//очищаем Timeout при новом запуске
  var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
    langText = "Привет!<br>Текст,<br>Текст ";
  (function e() {
    if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
      document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
      var t = text.slice(-1);
      if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
      mytimeout = setTimeout(e, 100);
    }
  }());
};
```

```css
        .lang{
  display: flex;
}
.lang a{
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.lang a:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.lang a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
    <a class="en" href="#">English</a>
    <a class="de" href="#">Deutsche</a>
    <a class="ru" href="#">Русский</a>
  </div>
  <div class="index-title-main">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: Да, возможно не до конца разобрался. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант. Простите, что несколько переиначил. К тому же, я не эксперт в JS, пусть знающие поправят, если можно лучше)

```js
let PRINT_INTERVAL = 100;

let STR = {};

STR.en = "Hi!\nText,\nText ";
STR.de = "Hallo!\nText,\nText ";
STR.ru = "Привет!\nТекст,\nТекст ";

let timeout = null;


// Функция печати

function type(str, index = 0)
{
  if(index === 0)
    contents.innerHTML = "";
  
  if(str[index] !== undefined)
  {
    let symbol = str[index];
    
    if(symbol === "\n")
      symbol = "<br>";
    
    contents.innerHTML += symbol;
  }
  
  timeout = setTimeout(function()
  {
    type(str, index + 1);
  }, PRINT_INTERVAL);
}

type(STR.en); // Печатаем текст по умолчанию при загрузке


// Проставляем события для каждой кнопки

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("div.lang > a");

buttons.forEach(function(buttonElement)
{
  let lang = buttonElement.className;
  
  buttonElement.onclick = function()
  {
    clearTimeout(timeout);  // Отменяем ранее запущенную печать
    
    // Делаем крошечный таймаут, чтобы избежать потенциальной гонки данных
    
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      type(STR[lang]);
    }, 1);
  }
});
```

```css
.lang {
  display: flex;
}
.lang a {
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.lang a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.lang a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
  <a class="en" href="#">English</a>
  <a class="de" href="#">Deutsche</a>
  <a class="ru" href="#">Русский</a>
</div>
<div class="index-title-main">
  <h1 id="contents"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, тоже хороший вариант. У меня правда он не такой как в примере. В моем случае язык берется с `localStorage`, а если он пуст, то с `window.navigator.userLanguage/window.navigator.language`. Но так как snippet не дает с ними работать, пришлось немного изменить пример.

Answer (score 1):

Как то дико много кода

```js
async function* generator(text, t = 100) {
  text = [...text]
  while (text.length) {
    await new Promise((s) => setTimeout(s, t))
    yield text.shift()
  }
}

let gen = { return: () => null }
async function writer(text, textArea) {
  await gen.return()
  textArea.textContent = ''
  gen = generator(text)
  let temp
  while ((temp = await gen.next(), !temp.done)) {
    textArea.textContent += temp.value
  }
}

// +++ test

const text = {
  en: 'I have this typewriter effect.',
  ru: 'У меня есть такой эффект печатающей машинки.'
}

const textArea = document.querySelector('[data-text]');

['en', 'ru'].forEach((v) => document.querySelector(`[data-${v}]`)
  .addEventListener('click', () => writer(text[v], textArea))
)
// default
writer(text.ru, textArea)
```

```html
<button data-en>en</button>
<button data-ru>ru</button>
<div data-text></div>
```